# How are memory allocations smaller than PAGE_SIZE handled in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system

Let's say a process asks to `mmap` just 50 bytes of memory. Will an entire page be allocated for this process? Is the rest of it just wasted? Also, how is this handled in kernel allocation functions like `kmalloc`?

Comment: Since a mmap() request for *"just 50 bytes"* cannot start anywhere, but rather must be page aligned, that is a strong hint as to what is going on.  IOW it is not possible to request or get an allocation of the back-half of a page.  Also the virtual memory uses page tables, not segment tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man 3p mmap`:

> The implementation **performs mapping operations over whole pages**.  Thus, while  the  argument **`len` need not meet a size or alignment constraint**, the implementation shall include, in any mapping operation, any partial page specified by the range `[pa,pa+len)`.

So, practically speaking, when you `mmap` 50 bytes you will actually map a whole page.

About the kernel situation, there is a page allocator (`get_free_pages()/alloc_pages()` or something like that), but they are low level functions, used mainly in memory management code.

The normal [`kmalloc()`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-kmalloc.html) functionis somewhat similar to user space `malloc()`: it will allocate whole pages internally but then it will divide them into smaller pieces to be used by the caller.